# How to lock row for multi worker rate limit?

Tags: postgresql

I have multiple workers distributed across multiple nodes that scrape HTML.  I need to specify a rate limit in the system so no domain gets more than 1 request every 5 seconds.

Each worker has access to a shared database (PostgreSQL) so I created a table with 2 columns:

> domain key, last scan date

In the worker code I want to check the last scan date before making a request.  The problem is thousands of workers could get the same domain at almost the same instant if tasks are distributed round robin so if they all read at once they will see no recent scan and all fire off requests.  So I need a way to lock the field so the first worker to check engages a lock, makes the scan and then updates the scan date and releases the lock.  Then all the other workers can check to see if a lock exists on the row and reject the task so it is re-scheduled.

I read the manual page of locks and found it very confusing.  It said all locks are table lock and I didn't really understand what it means about conflicts.  I am going to need multiple workers to be able to lock/unlock different rows at the same time and also check if a lock exists before placing lock so that the worker doesn't hang waiting for the lock to release and can move onto next task.

What type of lock do I need?  Are there any good examples showing this type of lock?

If I just wrap each process in a transaction will that work?

Comment: You can try “shedlock” https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your core code would be the block:

```
begin;
  set transaction isolation level read committed; -- should already be the default
  select domain_key
    from your_table
   where last_scan_date < now() - interval '5 seconds'
     for update skip locked
   limit 1;
-- Do your stuff here, and issue a rollback if it fails
  update your_table
     set last_scan_date = <value goes here>
   where domain_key = <value goes here>;
commit;
```

I expect this will be used in a host language.  The following example snippet of a worker is in python:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect('<db connect parameters>')
conn.autocommit = false
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("set transaction isolation level read committed;") 
c.execute("""
   select domain_key
     from your_table
    where last_scan_date < now() - interval '5 seconds'
    order by last_scan_date  
      for update skip locked
    limit 1
""")
domain_key = c.fetchone()[0]
if domain_key:
    result = process_url(domain_key)  # <-- This is your scraping routine
    if result == 'Ok':
        c.execute("""
          update your_table
             set last_scan_date = now() 
           where domain_key = %s
        """, (domain_key,))
        conn.commit()
    else:
        conn.rollback()
```

Comment: The "do your stuff here" part is an http request so its not something I can roll back.  I want to prevent the request happening so I don't take peoples websites offline by hitting them with too many requests.  The task comes in via message queue then I need to check db to see last time that domain had a request so multiple requests are prevented.

Comment: @Guerrilla What failure modes do you anticipate?  Is the 5 second limit between the start of one request and the start of the next, or between the end of one request and the start of the next?

Comment: @Guerrilla  The mechanics of how you execute it is up to you.  There is no need to roll back the work that your worker does outside of its PostgreSQL session.  What I showed is the code that you would execute in your workers' PostgreSQL sessions from whatever process in whatever host language would perform the scrape.  If your process cannot manage a transaction around `select . . . for update` and follow up with a `commit` or `rollback`, then how do you expect to be able to manage locks in the database?

Comment: @james if a domain has had a request in last 5 seconds or if a lock exists for domain indicating a request in progress then the message is rejected.  This causes the message to be re-queued to a dead letter exchange with a TTL of 5 seconds.  When it expires in that queue it is returned to the main queue.  The important think for me is workers do not hang and wait the 5 seconds, they need to reject and move on so no wasted processing time.

Comment: @MikeOrganek The point is the last scan date needs to be locked first before the scan starts and then remain locked until the http request completes.  I can't correlate that requirement to your answer.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Guerrilla If worker1 uses `select ... for update skip locked limit 1`, it puts a lock on a single record that will be held until worker1's transaction is completed.  When worker2 does `select ... for update skip locked limit 1` the query will ignore the record locked by worker1 and grab and lock another record if any are available.  Each worker should keep the lock on its record, perform the scrape and, when done, issue the `update` on its locked record, and then `commit` the transaction.  In case of error, the worker or its disconnection issues a `rollback`, freeing its locked row.

Comment: @Guerrilla  Added an example of using this from within python

Comment: Ah, I missed your previous comment.  I wasn't aware of "for update".  Will try it out

Comment: @Guerrilla  I verified behavior with multiple `psql` sessions open simultaneously.  I suspect one stumbling block you faced is that the entire selected row is locked.  The operations do not lock individual columns.

Comment: I have a question.  How does this work with an Upsert?  If I do an insert as the domain may never have been scanned before then do the "for update" inside the on conflict will this still lock properly for other processes?

Comment: @Guerrilla  You should not allow a scraping worker to insert rows into this table.  This table implements semaphores per `domain_key`, and allowing a scraping worker to add a new `domain_key` as part of the scraping process complicates the scheme since something outside of this locking process is guiding the scraping workers.  They need to lock the row before processing a `domain_key`.  I also recommend that you not do upserts to this table.  Adding new `domain_key` rows should be under the strict control of a single process that can deal with key conflicts within its context.

Comment: OK makes sense.  I will handle that in the process that generates the queue.  Thank you very much for the advice.